# Access an object from an other class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pixi.js

I have a JavaScript function to create a spaceship object. In my function spaceship_build() i draw my ship with pixijs. Additionaly i create a object "spaceship_object" to give them object some properties like energy or shipclass. Now i have the problem, that i can't access the spaceship_object properties in my other Classes. How can i access the object properties from the spaceship_build function?

My soltuion was, that i include the function fly_left in the function spaceship_build (closures). But that is not really nice, because i have other functions who must access the object too. My idea was to return the object, but i don't know how i should do that.

```
$("#b_schiff_beantragen").click(function() { 
if (!spaceship_object) { 
spaceship_object = spaceship_build(); 

} 
spaceship_draw(spaceship_object); 
$(".energie").css("visibility", "visible"); 
$("#b_schiff_zerstoeren").css("visibility", "visible"); 
$("#energiewertdiv").css("visibility", "visible"); 
});

  $("#b_nav_li").click(function() {

    flyleft(spaceship_object);
    console.log("Linksflug");
    console.log(spaceship_object.energy);
}); 



function flyleft(spaceship_object) {
    if (ship_energy(spaceship_object.energy) == true) {
    spaceship.x -= 50;  

    spaceship_object.energy -= 1;
    ship_energy(spaceship_object.energy);
    }
    mapborder850();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make fly_left accept a spaceship object as a parameter like this:

```
function fly_left(spaceship_object) {
    if (ship_energy(spaceship_object.energy) == true) {
        spaceship.x -= 50;  
        spaceship_object.energy -= 1;
        ship_energy(spaceship_object.energy);
    }
    mapborder850();
}
```

Then pass the object created by `spaceship_build` like this:

```
var spaceship_object = spaceship_build();
fly_left(spaceship_object)
```

Make sure you keep a reference to that spaceship object whenever you need to call `fly_left`

The `spaceship_build` returns an object which you can store in a variable like I've shown you above.Make all the functions that need that object accept a parameter(which in your case is the spaceship_object you created)

**UPDATE** 
You need to store your spaceship_object out of any event handler (like .click()) like this:

```
function flyleft(spaceship_object) {
    if (ship_energy(spaceship_object.energy) == true) {
        spaceship.x -= 50;
        spaceship_object.energy -= 1;
        ship_energy(spaceship_object.energy);
    }
    mapborder850();
}

var spaceship_object = spaceship_build();

$("#b_left").click( function() {
    flyleft(spaceship_object);
    console.log(spaceship_object.energy);
});
```

The reason you couldn't access the original spaceship(apart from the wrong syntax on the `click` handler) was that you created a new object instance each time you clicked the `#b` button(so the original spaceship was lost)

Or if you want to initialize the spaceship during the click event but have a global reference try that:

```
var spaceship_object = null;
$("#b_left").click( function() {
    if(!spaceship_object) spaceship_object = build_spaceship();
    flyleft(spaceship_object);
    console.log(spaceship_object.energy);
});
```

Comment: Thats not working because i have a jquery .click handler between.

`var spaceship_object = spaceship_build();

  $("#b_left").click(spaceship_object , function() {
 flyleft(spaceship_build());
 console.log(spaceship_object.energy);
}); 



function flyleft(spaceship_object) {
 if (ship_energy(spaceship_object.energy) == true) {
 spaceship.x -= 50; 
 
 spaceship_object.energy -= 1;
 ship_energy(spaceship_object.energy);
 }
 mapborder850();
}`

Comment: @Whiteheat I will update my answer in a couple of minutes

Comment: With this solution, the spaceship was already build, before i press my button. The variable starts automatically the spaceship_build() function by initializing. That was the reason, why i have tried to put the variable in the .click function.

Comment: Ok then move the spaceship initialization inside the click event

Comment: @Whiteheat let me know if my new solution helped you

Comment: Thank you very much, now it works fine! I have had another problem with the ship delete function. When my spaceship fly into the sun, i delete my spaceship_object. Therefore i had used "delete spaceship_object" and set my spaceship_object.energy = 0. But then i had the problem, that my spaceship energy was not deleted correctly. Setting simply the spaceship_object to null, solved the problem :)

Comment: Today i found a bug in this solution. When executing the flyleft function, a second spaceship object is created.

Comment: I'm sorry but with the code you provided me with I cannot see how this is possible

Comment: I have updated my code in the post. There you can see my whole code. linksflug() means fly_left(). i have them only translated from german.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167954/discussion-between-manos-kounelakis-and-whiteheat).